# Mockito verification is contradicting itself

Tags: mockito, verify

I have a mocked service, and I'm not able to verify it's being hit. To check that I was hitting the mock, I put a stub in:

```
when(dao.wrote(6789)).thenReturn(true);
```

I verified in the debugger that it was correctly returning the value. But this failed:

```
verify(dao).wrote(6789);
```

Irritatingly, this also failed:

```
verifyZeroInteractions(dao);
```

Scratching my head over how the method could have been both not called, and not not called!

Comment: Did `verifyZeroInteractions(dao)` list the recorded interactions with `dao`? Can you post them here? (Also, can you confirm that `dao.wrote` is public and non-final?)

Comment: Also, any chance we could see the complete test case including the `setup` method?